# How can I reduce elements in object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object like this:

```
result: 
     > rows:
       > 0: {key: Array(4), value: 3}
          > key: (4) ["Person", "2020-06-24", "Product, "00000000008"]
            value: 3
       > 1: {key: Array(4), value: 10}
          > key: (4) ["Person", "2020-06-25", "Product, "00000000009"]
            value: 10
       > 2: {key: Array(4), value: 10}
          > key: (4) ["Person", "2020-06-25", "Product, "00000000008"]
            value: 10
```

Now, what I need to do is to reduce this result checking for the same code (for example 00000000008) and sum the value, to obtain:

(for example)

```
00000000008   value: 13
```

Now, my problem is how to do, I have tried to use first a map and then a reduce, but I don't understand how can I check for the same code and sum the value.

How can I do?

I have tried in this way, but it doesn't work:

`res` is the object with the values

```
let example = res.rows.map((element)=> {
        console.log("ELEMENT IS ", element)
        let example1 = element.key[3].reduce(function(element, v){
          if(ref.hasOwnProperty(v))
            element[ref[v]] += v;
          else {
            ref[v] = element.length;
            element.push(prev = v)
          }
          return element
        }, [])
      })
      console.log("element", element)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Array.map` method is useful for data transformations, but if you have to aggregate is mostly expensive because you have also to `Array.filter` the non-aggregated values.

You can use [`Array.reduce` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead in order to build your own object:

```js
let result = {
  rows: [
    {
      key: ["Person", "2020-06-24", "Product", "00000000008"],
      value: 3
    },
    {
      key: ["Person", "2020-06-25", "Product", "00000000009"],
      value: 10
    },
    {
      key: ["Person", "2020-06-25", "Product", "00000000008"],
      value: 10
    }
  ]
}

let output1 = result.rows.reduce((acc, current) => {
  let key = current.key[3];
  // adding value to the accumulator
  acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + current.value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(output1);

let output2 = result.rows.reduce((acc, current) => {
  // check if key is already present
  let found = acc.find(v => v.key == current.key[3])
  // if it is, update the current value
  if (found) {
    found.value += current.value;
  }
  // otherwise create a new one
  else {
    acc.push({ key: current.key[3], value: current.value });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output2)
```

Answer (score 1):

create your own hashmap and loop over the result object once for all values

```
const hashmap = {};

rows.forEach(v => {
  hashmap[v.product] = (hashmap[v.product] || 0) + v.value;
});

// then are you able to access any product value on O(1)
const total = hashmap['00000000008'];

console.log({total});
// total: 13
```